# Is this data encryption process secure?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, php

I have created the following encryption process which I will be using to store CD keys inside my database. Before I use it, however, I need to make sure that this is as secure as possible.

From what I see, there are two primary concerns:

- The storage of the private key must be extremely secure. If someone gets a hold of the primary key, they can decrypt all the data in my database
- The encryption method must be as secure as possible

Is there a better way to securely store data in this scenario? If not, how can I ensure that this process is as secure as possible?

Here's my code:

```
public static function encrypt_key($key)
{
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_CAST_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        return $iv . openssl_encrypt ($key, 'AES-256-CBC', '32 bit private key', 0, $iv);
}

public static function decrypt_key($key)
{
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_CAST_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
        $iv = substr($key, 0, $iv_size);
        return openssl_decrypt(substr($key, $iv_size), 'AES-256-CBC', '32 bit private key', 0, $iv);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several improvements that can be made to the functions you've given, based on my knowledge.

### Obvious threats

First, and most important, **keep your private key secure**, and **make it external to the function definition** (e.g., a second argument). I would recommend spending significant effort solving this problem. Is this per-user encryption, or application-wide encryption? If it's per-user, then why not use a key derivation algorithm, such as [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)? If it's application-wide, then good luck with secure storage - I've thought about it before, and it seems non-trivial for a typical web app. Just make sure that you **don't store the private key along with the source, nor (obviously) in the same database**.

Also, as an aside: never use symmetric encryption for anything that's password-like. Use a one-way hash instead. I'm assuming, for this answer, that you need to actually *recover* the original CD key, rather than just verify a match.

Second, I'm dubious of the use of MCRYPT_RAND. It sounds like it might be [the same PRNG as rand()](http://phpsecurity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Insufficient-Entropy-For-Random-Values.html#attacking-php-s-random-number-generators), which is not ideal. **Generating the IV with MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM** is what I'd recommend - /dev/random and /dev/urandom are both considered top-notch sources of cryptographic random numbers on Unix-based systems. Note that you *don't* generally want to use /dev/random for a web application, because it would open up an easy DoS vector - and [/dev/urandom should suffice](http://sockpuppet.org/blog/2014/02/25/safely-generate-random-numbers/) outside of embedded environments, anyway.

### Other implementation issues

Now, with the major vulnerabilities that I can spot taken care of, a few more fine-grained details:

You're mixing OpenSSL and mcrypt functions. Also, openssl_encrypt is not documented in the official PHP docs (I suspect it's documented for C somewhere, though...). It might be better to use [mcrypt_encrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) instead, since it's explicitly documented for PHP.

You're mixing CAST-256 and AES-256, as well. You should probably stick with AES-256 throughout, since that's the generally-advised standard algorithm for strong symmetric encryption. Note that [AES-256 is MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 used with a 256-bit key](http://www.leaseweblabs.com/2014/02/aes-php-mcrypt-key-padding/), and is NOT the same as Rijndael-256, which is something that I hadn't previously realized (the more you know!).

I'm not sure about the preferred cipher mode, but CBC is one that I have seen recommended for AES, at least. Hopefully someone else will have some input.

Comment: By per-user, do you mean as in using the user's password to encrypt their keys?

Comment: Using the user's password to derive a per-user private key, yes. Hence the suggestion to use Password-Based Key Derivation Function 2 (PBKDF2) :). It's a technique used by many sites that need to encrypt user data in a way that *only* that one user can decrypt, such as [LastPass](https://helpdesk.lastpass.com/account-settings/general/password-iterations-pbkdf2/).

Comment: Okay, but what if the user's password is cracked? Is there an alternative solution?

Comment: Hmm... you're right, passwords in normal usage are going to be a weak link. Then again, in the event of a security breach, the contents of the webserver might be leaked, as well as the database itself. An approach that might work is to combine the user's password with some server-provided data, and then use that combination in the KDF. That way, if a database-only breach occurs, users with a password of "password" would still be protected (since the server's secret is still secure). However, this is getting into territory that's beyond my current expertise, so I might have missed something.

Comment: I was thinking something similar. I'm also going to PM you with a seperate question.

Comment: Sure, go for it. I'm about to log off for the night, but I'll check my mailbox in the morning.

Comment: It looks like stackexchange doesn't even have support for PM. Where can I contact you?

Comment: Feel free to send me an email - my email address should be listed in my profile, and if not, it's my-first-name dot my-last-name at gmail. Write something in the subject line indicating it's related to crypto/infosec, so I can find it. EDIT: ah, looks like the email address ISN'T publicly visible in StackExchange profiles. Oh well. Still: my-first-name dot my-last-name at gmail

Comment: There's an issue. I can only use PBKDF2 when the user is actually given a CD-key. Before then, I will need to encrypt it without their password. Any ideas?

Comment: In that case, you might be able to use two layers of encryption. You could, for instance, encrypt it first with the server's private key (taking appropriate measures to keep this safe), and then after they've provided a password, also encrypt it using a key derived from their password. This would mean that there are THREE breaches that need to occur: webserver breach, DB breach, and password breach. At some point you might want to look into using client-side encryption (in JavaScript), as well as server-side.

Comment: How does client-side encryption work, and why would you need to use it? Can you please explain more?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26056/discussion-between-mightyspaj-and-ethan-kaminski).